# populate array with UNIQUE random numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I have an array :

```
var array = new Array();
```

Here is the random function, which gives a random number between `min` and `max` (seen in a previous Stackoverflow topic) :

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

This array is meant to have 9 cells. I would like to populate it with random number, with the important condition that each of those number are unique, which means a number in this array cannot be found twice or more.So finally, here is where I am stuck (whole code) :

```
var array = new Array();

function randomIntFromInterval(min,max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

// populate the variable "array" with 9 different
// random numbers
function randomlyInitializeArray() {
    var random = 0;

    // For each cell (9 cells) in my "array"
    for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {

        // Return a number between 1 & 9
        random = randomIntFromInterval(1, maxLength);

        /*  Verifying if this random number is already in 
            the "array" /!\ stuck here /!\ */
    }
}
```

So, what is the logic for populate an array with 9 unique (different) number ?

Comment: Populate it with 1,2,3...9 and then [shuffle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array?s=1|1.6991).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not get an array from 1 to - max then shuffle it

```js
//+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
//@ http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle [v1.0]

function shuffle(o) { //v1.0
  for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
  return o;
};

function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

// populate the variable "array" with 9 different
// random numbers
function randomlyInitializeArray(min, max) {
  var start = min;
  var randomMax = randomIntFromInterval(min, max)
  var myArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; start <= randomMax; myArray[i++] = start++);

  myArray = shuffle(myArray);
  console.log("Min: "+min);
  console.log("Max: "+max);
  console.log("random Max: "+randomMax)
  
  console.log(myArray)

}

randomlyInitializeArray(2,40);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I understood your solution !

Comment: just realized i mis-read your question and made it so it has from min to max of the random numbers not 1-9, but ill leave it like this as it can easily be made to go from 1-9 by passing in 1 and 9 to `randomlyInitializeArray`

Comment: Yep, I just have to change your values, the algorithmic is clear for me thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want 9 random unique numbers from 1-9? That seems to me the same as wanting the numbers 1 to 9 in a random order.

This can be done simply with:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].sort(function () { // shuffle
    return Math.random() - 0.5; // returns > 0 ~50% of the time
});
```

Otherwise you could do something like:

```
var array = [];
while (array.length < 9) {
    array = array_unique(array.concat([ get_random_number() ]);
}
console.log(array);
```

Most frameworks have an `array_unique` function in one way or another, or just write your own.

There are faster ways to do this but the explicit inclusion of the call to `unique()` makes this implementation easy to understand and verify.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get 9 random numbers from a specific interval(using that function):

You could use a `do-while` loop to get random numbers until you have an unique one.

You can check if a number is already in an array via `contains()` function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    do {
        random = randomIntFromInterval(1, maxLength);
    while( array.contains(random) );          // will return false if random isn't asigned

    array.push(random);
}
```

If you do not care about the interval, and you just want 9 unique values (1-9 in a random order) you can create the array with 1-9 and shuffle it with:

```
var myArray = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
newArray = shuffle(myArray);

function shuffle(o){ 
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
```

shuffle method taken from [how can I shuffle an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you, this example is well suited for my application so thumbs up !

Comment: @Zeratops you can always upvote an answer you found helpful rather than just saying thanks in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a `while` loop, something like

```
function unique_nums(n) {
    var myarray = [];
    for (var i=0;i<n;i++){
        var next_num = Math.random();
        while (myarray.indexOf(next_num) !== -1) {
            next_num = Math.random();
        }
        myarray.push(next_num);
    }
    return myarray;
}
```

This will ensure that the random number doesn't exist within the array before it is `push`ed.

Comment: Thank you for answering Stick, however I prefer the shuffle() method because it is better suited for my needs.